# Global Variables in static PHP classes

Tags: php, global

Is there a way to use a global variable everywhere in the code?

I want to use a Path variable to the located configured Folder in each Path I'll declare in my code.

Here's my Code:
Index.php

```
<?php
     require_once('Common.php');
     require_once('Path.php');
?>
```

Common.php

```
<?php 
     $RootPath = '.';//in this case its root
     //add the RootPath for global using
     $GLOBALS['RootPath'] = $RootPath;
?>
```

Path.php

```
<?php
     class Path {
          public static $TemplatePath = $GLOBALS['RootPath'].'/Template.php';
     }
?>
```

This won't work because it says, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" when I try to call $GLOBALS when declaring a static variable.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in Anticipation
Alex

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Its as less code as possable, ill answer my own post 7 hs later (-.-), or you post it as an answer.

Comment: Posted it as an answer, happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

It's very common to use them to define certain path's, f.e.

```
define('PATH_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('PATH_TEMPLATES', PATH_ROOT.'/templates');
```

Comment: Declaring my RootPath as a constant variable solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Class constants and static class variables cannot be initialized with dynamic data.

What about defining method instead?

```
 class Path {
          public static getTemplatePath()
          {
            return $GLOBALS['RootPath'].'/Template.php';
          }
     }
```

And why you would keep settings as global variables, and not encapsulate them in some kind of [Registry](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_registry)?

Comment: The class Path is used for Path-Sources.. ill add about 20-30 Paths, but i wont declare a Method for each Path-Variable..

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to use a global variable inside a function that is out of the scope, you must first declare it within the function/class method with "global $varname".

In your case:

Common.php

```
<?php 
     $RootPath = '.';//in this case its root
     //add the RootPath for global using
     // $GLOBALS['RootPath'] = $RootPath; // no need for this, $[GLOBALS] is about the Superglobals, $_SERVER, $_SESSION, $_GET, $_POST and so on, not for global variables.
?>
```

Path.php

```
<?php
     class Path {
          public static $TemplatePath;// = $GLOBALS['RootPath'].'/Template.php';

          public method __construct(){
               global $RootPath;
               self::TemplatePath =  $RootPath.'/Template.php';
          }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why would someone initialize a static variable in a constructor? This requires creating an instance just to initialize the static variables of a class. And each instance could possibly override the class variable. Bad design IMO

Comment: You are right. I am just starting with OOP, and obviously haven't got the patterns thing down yet.

Answer (score 0):

Tranform your (bad) public static attribute, to a public static getter/setter.

Also, global variables are a bad pratice, introducing side effect and name collision.

Comment: I know that is a bad practice but its better than changing 40 paths because the root directory of the framework has changed.

Comment: It's not the fact that you store the path in one place - **that is a good practice**. The bad practice is to store it in **a global variable**. As @Darhazer said it, a Registry is a good pattern to handle those cases (however please, don't make your registry a Singleton. Make it an injected dependency please...).

Comment: Before deciding if you have enough time, please think about the time you'll lose when you'll have troubles with testing your app because of your singleton, or all the other known singleton-relted issues =)

Comment: I guess I'll do that in a few days (:, Thanks anyway for your help.